# Getting the Fourier Transform from Time Averaging of the Stockwell Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I am working on the Stockwell Transform and want to show that time averaging of the Stockwell Transform yields the spectrum of the function $u(t)$.

$G(t'-t,\omega)$ being a Gaussian Window Function, with $t'$ being the center time.

$$
G(t'-t,\omega) = ae^{-b(t'-t)^2}
$$

satisfying the condition

$$
\int G(t_\alpha,\omega) dt_\alpha = 1
$$

The Stockwell Transform is defined as

$$
S(t,\omega)=\int{u(t')} G(t'-t,\omega) e^{-i \omega t'} dt'
$$

It is claimed that by the integral properties of the Gaussian function, the relation between $S(t'-t,\omega)$ and $u(\omega)$ (the Fourier
transform of $u(t)$) is

$$
\int S(t,\omega)\; dt = u(\omega)
$$

---

**Attempt at a proof**

$$
\rm{To\; show\; that\;} \int S(t,\omega)\; dt = u(\omega)
$$

Have done time averaging as $\int S(t,\omega) dt$ assuming the condition $\int G(t'-t,\omega) dt' = 1$

$$
\int S(t,\omega) dt = \int \int{u(t')}\; [G(t'-t,\omega) e^{-i \omega t'} dt']\;dt
$$

$$
= \int \bigg[\int{u(t')} e^{-i \omega t'} dt'\bigg]\; G(t'-t,\omega)\; dt
$$

Because $G(t'-t,\omega)$ is dependent on $t'$, I hit a wall.

The specific expression for $G(t'-t,\omega)$ is a Gaussian Function

$$
G(t'-t,\omega) = a\; e^{-b(t'-t)^2}
$$

Comment: Can't you derive the inner integral of $\int S(t,\omega) dt = \int\left(\int u(t')\,G(t'-t,\omega)\,e^{-i \omega t'}\,dt'\right) dt$ while treating $t$ as a constant? Or interchange the order of integration and evaluate the inner integral of $\int S(t,\omega) dt = \int u(t') \left(\int G(t'-t,\omega)\,dt\right) e^{-i \omega t'}\,dt'$ while treating $t'$ as a constant?

Comment: What would the inner integral evaluate to when treating $t$ constant?  Am not quite sure whether I can keep using the general function $G(t′−t,\omega)$ or be forced to use the actual expression for $G(t′−t,\omega)$.

Comment: It seems to me you're not going get very far until you use an actual expression for $G(t′−t,\omega)$ since it's a function of both integration variables.

Comment: Have tried integration by parts, but led me to some more difficulties.  Have a feeling that with the integral properties of the Gaussian function, the relation between $S(t, \omega)$ and $u(\omega)$ (the Fourier
transform of $u(t)$ gives the result.